# Why is my for loop running infinitly?

Tags: c

Entering the size of the array works. But the Enter integers for loop  runs infinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, array[5], i;

    printf("Enter the size of the array.");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    array[c];

    printf("Enter the integers to fill the array.");

    for (i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        //if (array[0] >= array[i]) {
        //    ...
        //}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-by-one bug, the for-loops need to use `<` instead of `<=`.  As-is, the buffer overflow corrupts the value of the loop variable so it loops much more often than intended.

Answer (score 4):

Your array is of a fixed size 5. The line `array[c];` doesn't resize it. It's an array access (possibly an out of bounds access) and therefore your entire program has undefined behavior.

To define a VLA, you must move the array *declaration* after the call to `scanf`<sup>1</sup>:

```
int c;
printf("Enter the size of the array.");
scanf("%d",&c);

int array[c];
```

Then, make sure your loop condition is correct. In C array indices a 0-based, meaning we loop on the interval [0, c-1] and not [0, c].

```
for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
```

And as a final point of contention, notice how I moved all variable declaration to just before their initial use. Organizing your code like that (with a certain locality of data and execution) has a tendency to clarify what you write. So I strongly advise you to do this.

---

1. And be sure to **check** the return value of scanf. You *do not* want to define an array if the call to the library function failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. `array[c]` refers to an element at 'c' position in `array` and doesn't do any fruitful job. Try removing that and check once.
2. In your for loop, you're reading and printing elements from `0 to c`, which means you took `c+1` elements instead of c elements. Make it : `for(i=0;i<c;++i)`